Minimum polynomials of elements in purely inseparable extensions
I am trying to solve this exercise in field theory :
Assume that $k$ is a field of prime characteristic $p$, and assume that $L$ is a purely inseparable extension of $k$. Prove that the minimum polynomial $f(x)$ of any $z\in{L}$ is of the form $f(x) = {x^{p^n}}+a$ where $n$ is a positive integer and $a$ is a non-zero element of $k$.
I tried arguing as follows : Assume that ${\rm deg}(f) = m$, and that $n$ is the positive integer such that
$${p^{n}}\leq{m}<{p^{n+1}}.$$
Since $k$ is of characteristic $p$ an irreducible polynomial in $k[x]$ must have non-zero coefficients only for those exponents which are multiples of $p$. Thus, $$f(z) = {g_1}({z^p})=0$$ for a non-constant ${g_1}(x)\in{k[x]}.$ But since $L$ is a purely inseparable extension of $k$, ${z^p}\in{L}$ must also be inseparable, and so it must be the case that $$f(x)={g_2}(x^{p^2}).$$ I can continue in this fashion to conclude that $$f(x)={g_{n}}(x^{p^n}).$$
I am trying to prove that all coefficients of exponents of the form $x^{lp^n}$ must be $0$ for $l>1.$ This is where I am stuck! Is my reasoning correct so far, and how do I move forward?

I think the answer of this question depends on how you define purely inseparable extension. I know one definition for $k\subseteq K$ being purely inseparable is simply every element in $K$ has irreducible polynomial  over $k$ with form $x^{p^n}-a$ ($n\geqq 0$), $p=\text{char }k$, $a\in k$.

Interesting! The definition that I learned is that the minimum polynomial of every element of $z\in{L}$ is not separable. i.e. it does not have distinct roots.

You are actually almost done: once you've gotten all the way to $g_n$ you have now ended up with a polynomial of degree less than $p$, but it is still true that $z^{p^n}$ is a root of $g_n$. It can no longer be an inseparable element of $L \setminus k$ since this would imply that $\deg g_n \ge p$, so now the only possibility is that $z^{p^n} \in k$ (meaning that $g_n$ has degree $1$) which is the desired conclusion.
It may be a little simpler to instead phrase this argument as a proof by induction on the degree of $z$ over $k$. You can write the induction in terms of proving the desired result for degrees $p^n \le m < p^{n+1}$ and then taking the $p$-th power for the inductive step.
